# Compile C to wasm, with same settings as WasmFiddle

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

Looking at the following [WasmFiddle](https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle//?6mao9), once compiled to wasm the file is 259bytes. I'm trying to from WasmFiddle move to my local environment, so i've downloaded and installed the [Emscripten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm) compiler.

Now, since the Emscripten environment adds extra features same code is 22KB.

**Q:** How can I compile the c code on my local machine, and keep it lean?
Even better how can I have the same output as the WasmFiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the sourcecode for the server-side component that WasmFiddle uses for compilation here:

https://github.com/wasdk/wasmexplorer-service/blob/master/scripts/compile.sh

It is very similar to c2wasm, which also provides a minimal output:

https://github.com/tpimh/wasm-toolchain

Answer (score 1):

A couple options using Emscripten's `emcc` can keep your outputted wasm file lean.

Optimization:

`-Oz`

Only my code (removes Emscripten framework code):

`-s ONLY_MY_CODE=1`

These flags should bring you very close to your desired 259 bytes.